# continue file uploading on navigation away

Tags: html, forms, file-upload, multipartform-data

this is probably a long shot, but I thought I should ask. I have a file upload form on my site and some files are large and take a long time to upload, is there any way that a user could navigate away from the page containing the multipart/form-data form without causing the upload stream to end?

Answer (score 0):

Consider opening the upload in another window, because as far as I'm aware the only way to keep uploading the file while the user navigates away is to not navigate away

1. you can do this by having full ajax navigation (you can even use [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API))
2. by keeping the page that the user uses in an iframe the size of the window
3. Use [web-workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), they work by creating a process that runs in the background.